# Форма_обратной_связи

Tags: php, wordpress, cms, form, отправка

На сайте, разработанном с помощью CMS WordPress, установлена форма обратной связи **CONTACT FORM 7**, все настроено, разрешено отправлять файлы до 50 mb, к отправке разрешены mp3, wma, wav, ogg. Форма не отправляет вложение. В чем может быть дело?

Comment: Это в настройках формы вы разрешили типы файлов? А на сервере?

Comment: на сервере увеличен лимит загрузки, все разрешения есть

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Обычно в шаблон формы вставляют поле для загрузки файла, а в тело письма забывают прикрепить его, вот так:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

У Вас так сделано?

Comment: Вы на сайт его сходите и посмотрите. Там до отправки дело не доходит.

Comment: сделано все так как на сайте разработчкиа плагина сказано.

Comment: в поле "Прикрепленный файл" добавлено значение [file-148], но отправление не проходит на сервере

Comment: Сейчас попробовал отправить маленький файл в 190кб и всё получилось. Проверьте подобные настройки (для htacess, но подобное есть и в php.ini):  php_value upload_max_filesize 20M и
php_value post_max_size 20M.

Answer (score 0):

Проблема оказалась в хостере, были отключены cgi скрипты.